# How to remove keyboard when user click on UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

i used following code to remove keyborad

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
self.view.endEditing(true)
 }

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

however it will work fine when i click any where in the screen but when i click on button(UIBUTTON) which is present in my screen the keyboard in not hide until i press return Key or touch anywhere in UIView
please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you test to put `textField.resignFirstResponder()` in the button's function?

Ex :

```
@IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Comment: Or self.view.endEditing(true)

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution would be to use:

```
 self.view.endEditing(true)
```